# Outlook email client doesn't allow image pasting

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I used to be able to paste in an image in a new email message on Outlook 16.16.25 on my Mac. But it no longer works. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I found a solution:

1. Open outlook
2. click New Email
3. Options
4. turn on the "Format Text" switch to turn on HTML mode

Answer (score 1):

Some of the features such as images are not supported in Plain Text emails.